# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression(Replace and Case Statement) in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the mentioned error while running the below query, i have tried several options such as adding cast (See below) but i am still getting the error.

I have included only the fields related to error in the below query.If i comment chiffre_daffaire_Caisse the query works. Thanks for advising

```
With CTE as (
SELECT 

WHEN D.F1034=3 THEN  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),D.F64), 111), '.', '')
                           ELSE 0 
END as Qty_Sold,


CASE WHEN [POS_TAB].F81 = 1 THEN REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),  Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 
Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),D.F65/NULLIF(D.F64,0)) as nvarchar) * cast(1.15 
as numeric(10,2)) ) as nvarchar) ), 111), '.', '')  ELSE
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 
Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),D.F65/NULLIF(D.F64,0)) as nvarchar) ), 111), '.', 
'')
END as UnitPrice


FROM 
             [dbo].[RPT_ITM_D] D
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RPT_ITM_D] REF ON (D.F01=REF.F01 AND 
D.F254=REF.F254 AND D.F126=REF.F126 AND D.F1056=REF.F1056 AND 
D.F1057=REF.F1057 AND REF.F1034 IN (3011,3012))
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RPT_ITM_D] QTY ON (D.F01=QTY.F01 AND 
 D.F254=QTY.F254 AND D.F126=QTY.F126 AND D.F1056=QTY.F1056 AND 
D.F1057=QTY.F1057 AND QTY.F1034 IN (3011,3012))
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[POS_TAB] ON (D.F01=POS_TAB.F01)
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].SDP_TAB ON (POS_TAB.F04=SDP_TAB.F04)
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo]. DEPT_TAB ON (SDP_TAB.F03=DEPT_TAB.F03)
            -- LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo]. PRICE_TAB ON  D.F01 = PRICE_TAB.F01

     where 

             D.F1034 IN (3,3012)

                          AND
               D.F254  = '2017/11/18' 


)

 Select 
 --SUM((Qty_Sold * UnitPrice)/100)  AS chiffre_daffaire_Caisse,  (Give Error 
 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
 Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.)

--SUM(CAST(((Qty_Sold * UnitPrice)/100) AS  numeric(12, 0))), (Give Error 
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.)

SUM(isnull(cast(((Qty_Sold * UnitPrice)/100) as numeric(12, 0)),0)) , (Give 
Error : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.)
-- I have even tried BigInt but its not working

from CTE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I had to `cast` the `Qty_Sold` as `Numeric` or `BigInt` as shown below.

```
SUM(isnull(cast(((CAST(Qty_Sold AS numeric) * UnitPrice)/100) as numeric(12, 0)),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TRY_CONVERT/CAST to find the offending values like below

```
TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),1)
```

Above query won't fail,but will have nulls for values that doesn't convert